# PHP - CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE ignored

Tags: php, curl, upload, byte

I would like to execute the callback function every X bytes uploaded, but I don't understand why php keeps calling the callback function way way more often.

here is my code:

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$converter); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, 'callback');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, 10485764);
$result=curl_exec ($ch); 

//$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
//print_r($info);
curl_close ($ch);

function callback($resource, $download_size, $downloaded, $upload_size, $uploaded) {
    echo $uploaded . '/' . $upload_size ."\r";
}
```

The file to upload is around 68 MB, the callback function should get executed 68 times (10485764 bytes = 1 MB), but it gets executed around 9k times...

The function should write the progress in a mysql db, that's why I need it to get executed less time.

Comment: Can you post cURL Information form your phpinfo?

Comment: @pamelus sure, here you go => http://puu.sh/iCsEj/1fd04da266.png

Btw my curl version is 7.30.0, the CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE has been implemented in CURL 7.10.

Also, my php version is 5.5.8

Comment: `CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE` is the size of the **read** buffer. It has nothing to do with writing or the progress function.

Comment: @Barmar if you check the comment from "xektrum at gmail dot com" @ http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#91952 you will see the exemple I am working from, that says the bigger the buffer is, the less often the callback will get executed.

Comment: That's for downloads, not uploads.

Comment: @Barmar I understand, is there any equivalent for upload?

Comment: Not that I can tell. You could just change your callback so it doesn't do anything if the new size is too close to the previous size.

Comment: Or check the time, and return immediately if too little time has passed since the previous callback.

Comment: @Barman I have used the first solution, I will post the Answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Barman stated, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE is related to download and won't work for upload.

The solution is to check the size and do something only if a certain amount of byte has been uploaded.

Exemple:

```
$i= 0;
$up = 0;

function callback($resource, $download_size, $downloaded, $upload_size, $uploaded) {
        global $i, $up;
        if ($uploaded > ($up + 1048576)){
            $i++;
            $up = $uploaded + 1048576;
            echo $i . ' => ' . formatBytes($uploaded) . '/' . formatBytes($upload_size) ."\r";
        }
}
```